# UserControl in DataTemplate doesn't applied style for font

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources, datatemplate, styles

I have a user control in a `DataTemplate`, The `Style` of a `TextBlock` doesn't change the `FontSize` but changes the `Background`.

Attached are the samples:

1. Create a WPF window.
2. Create a User control, `UserControl1`
3. Inside the Window paste the below code:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
            x:Key="TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound">
         <Setter Property="FontSize"
                 Value="20" />
         <Setter Property="Background"
                 Value="Blue" />
     </Style>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate">
         <StackPanel>
               <m:UserControl1 />
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
     <ContentControl FontSize="10">
         <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
                 <Button Click="Button_Click" />
                 <ContentControl  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}" />
                 <!--<m:UserControl1 />-->
         </StackPanel>
     </ContentControl>
   </Grid>
   ```
4. In the user control paste the following code:

   ```
   <UserControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplateInsideUserControl">
         <TextBlock Name="textBlockInResourse" Text="textBlockInsideUserControlResource"
                    Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <StackPanel>
       <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplateInsideUserControl}" />
           <Button Content="St" Click="Button_Click" />
           <TextBlock Name="textBlockInControl" Text="textBlockInsideUserControl"
                      Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound}" />
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```

We have 2 text blocks with the same background color, blue, but with different font sizes.

`textBlockInResourse FontSize = 20`, taken from the style `TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound`

`textBlockInControl FontSize = 10`, inherited value, why does it happen?

I have added a handle in the user control:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Style style = FindResource("TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound") as Style;
        textBlockInControl.Style = null;
        textBlockInControl.Style = style;
    }
```

And now the `Font` is set to the style `TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound`, and it's size is 20

Why now the `FontSize` is taken from the style `TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound`.

Thanks,
barak

Answer (score 1):

That's a very peculiar problem you have found there. I'm not sure why the `FontSize` is not affected when not in a `DataTemplate`... looking at the two property descriptions and remarks on MSDN, the only difference between them is that `TextBlock.FontSize` is also an `AttachedProperty`, but I can't see how that would affect anything.

I can however offer a solution to the problem if you're still interested. Try declaring your `Style` in your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then declare your `TextBlock` in your `UserControl` using `StaticResource` like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="text" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleFontAndBackgound}" />
```